# Check phonotactics constraints of nonwords with python

Tags: python

Are you aware of a method to check whether some nonwords respect the orthography and phonotactics constraints of English?

I'll give you an example:

```
        Word       ipa New_Word_0 New_Word_1 New_Word_2
0        cisp      sɪsp       cizp       zicp       cisb
1      defect    difɛkt     devect     defegt     defecd
2     flaccid   flæksɪd    vlaccid    flagcid    flaczid
3     hospice    hɑspʌs    hozpice    hosbice    hospize
4   hypocrite  hɪpʌkɹɪt  hybocrite  hypogrite  hypocride
5       scilk     skɪlk      zcilk      sgilk      scilg
6       scose     skoʊs      scoze      sgose      zcose
7     scrarsh    skɹɑɹʃ    scrarzh    sgrarsh    scrarge
8      scruch    skɹʌtʃ     zcruch     sgruch      scruj
9      scrush     skɹʌʃ     zcrush     sgrush     scruge
10     scunch    skʌntʃ     zcunch     sgunch      scunj
11    secrete    sɪkɹit    zecrete    segrete    secrede
12      skief     skaɪf      zkief      sgief      skiev
13     skurnt     skɝnt     zkurnt     sgurnt     skurnd
14      snusp     snʌsp      snuzp      znusp      snusb
15      spesk     spɛsk      zpesk      sbesk      spezk
16      spirp      spɝp      zpirp      sbirp      spirb
17     splink    splɪŋk     zplink     sblink     spling
18    splirth     splɝθ    zplirth    sblirth   splirthe
19     splope    sploʊp     zplope     sblope     splobe
20   splourth   sploʊɹθ   zplourth   sblourth  splourthe
21    splowth    splaʊθ    zplowth    sblowth   splowthe
22     spraif    spɹeɪf     zpraif     sbraif     spraiv
23     spreak     spɹik     zpreak     sbreak     spreag
24    spreece     spɹis    zpreece    sbreece    zpreece
25    sproath    spɹoʊθ    zproath    sbroath   sproathe
```

In the column `Word` there are valid nonwords in English (orthographically and phonologically valid).

I then generated new words changing some voiceless phonemes into voiced. The thing is this is done randomly so there are chances that the new words do not follow the phonotactics constraints of English. For example `flaczid` I suspect is not really correct. Or the word starting in `zc` as in `zcrush`. Maybe there is a list of onsets combination which are forbidden, but as far as I looked on the Internet I can't find anything useful.

Comment: I would try with regex and patterns for onset and coda.